# Which board is the best fit for my project?

Tags: arduino

I am designing a device that will have an accelerometer and temperature sensors. This device is intended to record patterns in activity of individuals throughout the day. The device will need to operate throughout the day, and should be able to withstand a lot of movement, possibly small weights and generally rough usage. It also needs to be small enough to be carried on a person, possibly latch onto backpacks and fit into pockets or latch onto the belt loops (not sure of the term?).

Which device would best suit my requirements ?

Looking around a bit, it seems the Lilypad is the only Arduino that is small enough. Are there other choices ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For size and very low thermal profile, look at the [FemtoDuino](http://www.femtoduino.com/):

[image: FemtoDuino]

The new design has on-board USB. Also, the board is so small that pressure / rough use stresses are not a big concern.

However, the headers are not the standard 0.1 inch type (obviously), in order to fit everything into that tiny form factor. This isn't an issue for a custom project, I suggest.

There is also the [LilyTiny](http://lilypadarduino.org/?p=523), quite small, and specifically designed as a wearable Arduino like the LilyPad, but with limited functionality compared to the FemtoDuino. It is, however, insufficiently specified for the sensors the question mentions - not enough pins exposed.

[image: LilyTiny]

Comment: How do you work with something that small ~Femtoduino ?

Comment: @AshRj  Must.... not.... **SNEEZE!**

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the [RFduino](http://www.rfduino.com/), currently (10-Apr-2013) in pre-order after a successful Kickstarter funding campaign. It looks like it has the size you need, and it has Bluetooth integrated, which many people expect their fitness devices to have for syncing (see: Fitbit).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the modest input requirements, the [Digispark](http://digistump.com/products/1) (~$9) might be a suitable fit.  It uses standard size headers, plugs directly into the USB port, and is based on the ATtiny so it has 6 I/O pins available.  Although they produced [laser cut acrylic cases](http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/cases) as part of their [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/digistump/digispark-the-tiny-arduino-enabled-usb-dev-board), I can't find them for sale now.

[image: Digispark]

They also produce [proto shields for it](http://digistump.com/products/2) (~$3):

[image: Digispark Proto Shield]

On the other hand, the [TinyDuino](http://tiny-circuits.com/products/tinyduino/asm2001/) is a full ATmega328 (Arduino Uno chip), with a coin cell clip built in for power **and mounting holes**.  The drawback to this option is that it is ~$20 and you also need a programmer module for ~$17.  The protoboards are about $4 each, and 3 options provide different pin spacing on each board.

[image: TinyDuino]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do any heavy lifting in the CPU, the Teensyduino 3.0 is an ARM based, 32 bit, Arduino API compatible board that is quite small and less than $20.

Has a number of breakout boards, including an SD card interface which might prove useful if you are logging a ton of data.

http://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy3.html